# duplicate cron process - python pm2

Tags: linux, python, aws-ec2

Our setup consists of a Python Flask application deployed on AWS EC2 with autoscaling, and it utilises a MySQL database.

We also have jobs scheduled on a separate Linux system, which triggers every 10 seconds, hitting the API endpoints at `https://api.example.com`.
The application runs under pm2.

Recently, we've encountered issues with data duplication arising from these scheduled jobs. Although the cron job is set correctly to execute every 10 seconds, we observed instances where the same job runs simultaneously with only microseconds apart.  Upon enabling API logs, we've confirmed these occurrences.

It's perplexing how these jobs execute simultaneously when they're scheduled to hit the API URL's every 10 seconds. We're seeking advice on methods or tools that could help us diagnose this issue, as well as strategies to prevent such simultaneous job executions.

Comment: The most obvious reason: a duplicate job spec.  Might want to check the cron logs of the job host. To prevent multiple cron batch jobs  from running concurrently on the same host - use for example `flock` https://serverfault.com/a/923242/37681 _-_ Always a good failure reason: bad application logic in general and no good failure mode when the batch that gets started every 10 seconds starts to take longer than  10 seconds. -_- Data duplication is usually best solved/prevented in the API itself, requiring good behaviour from the API users / clients is less reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Running repetitive job w/o checking for single copy of the job, especially in so short interval is direct call for troubles.

What you can do is to measure the run time of API call and set schedule to be on biggest interval. **AND** implement check so only one copy of the job is running. You can set job to be skipped if already run and send kind of alarm so you can (again) reconsider the scheduled interval.

Of course you can organise kind of queue of skipped jobs, but this depend a lot from the nature of job. And you risk to have constantly increasing queue.

Comment: Thank you, Romeo. We've developed a text file that logs 'START' at the beginning of our job and 'END' upon completion. Our shell script is designed to trigger a remote API call once 'END' is recorded in the text file. However, we've noticed instances where our API logs indicate that the same endpoint was accessed twice within milliseconds of each other.

Comment: We've examined the cron server logs and observed that each cron job is initiated with a 10-second interval. This makes it challenging to determine the cause of the issue. Currently, we lack a method to verify if the API endpoint is still being processed by PM2. We are seeking a solution to ascertain whether the issue originates from PM2 or the Cron scheduler.

Comment: AFAIK no scheduling manager will run the job(s) on exact time, there is always some drift. And as your step (for defining time) is one second you may expect shift from second or even more. My idea is to measure the time of API call and set check if call is in progress.